# String quotes elimination

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I'm trying to import a .csv file that contains some points which are geo-positions, but the import gives me the points wrapped in quotes. Is there any method to get them as pairs of real numbers?

I'm getting `"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}"` but I want `{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}`.

---

**Update**

Here is an example that produces output with the problem:

```
csvstring = "\"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}\",2\n\"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}\",3"; 
ImportString[csvstring, "CSV"]

{{"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}", 2},
 {"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}", 3}}
```

Comment: You could use `ToExpression` on your lists. Otherwise, without the CSV file and the code used to `Import`, it will be difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before "{26.2417`,-98.43201`},{26.2407`,-98.42469000000001`}". I got this error

Comment: Okay, can you please provide the *.csv file you have, or a sample of it if it's too large?

Comment: ... because your pasted expression structure is invalid (lacks enclosing {}). Without more details from your side anything more detailed will be a waste of time.

Comment: I-2,"{26.2417,-98.43201},{26.2407,-98.42469000000001}" that's the csv file, but you're right i miss lacks enclosing thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, what you have is not a valid CSV format file.

Comment: @george2079 I think it is valid.  Here's an example generated from an Excel .csv file: `csvstring = "\"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}\",2\n\"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}\",3"; ImportString[csvstring, "CSV"]`.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes if the quotation marks are in the file thats ok.

Comment: @Alberto I added my own example to your question.  If I've completely missed the point, please edit with a more appropriate example.

Comment: @george2079 Yeah, that's basically what happens in Excel when you enter an item that contains a comma (and save to CSV).  It puts quotes around the entry in the csv file.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ways. [`SemanticInterpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticInterpretation.html) is sort of fun but extremely slow:

```
SemanticInterpretation["{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}", List[_, _] ..]
```

Fixing up your data to fit [Yves Klett's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/131/yves-klett) suggestion is much faster:

```
ToExpression["{" <> "{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}" <> "}"]
```

Both yield

```
(*  {{26.2417`, -98.432`}, {26.2407`, -98.4247`}}  *)
```

If there were a bunch of them with the same format, then this will replace all of them:

```
import = {"{26.2417,-98.432},{26.2407,-98.4247}"};
import /. s_String /; 
   StringMatchQ[s, RegularExpression["{[0-9.-]*,[0-9.-]*},{[0-9.-]*,[0-9.-]*}"]] :> 
  ToExpression["{" <> s <> "}"]
```

Depending on what's in the CSV file, one might alter the [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html).  Conceivably, this might work:

```
RegularExpression["{.*}"]
```

Note: A problem with the data are the commas separating the coordinates, which appear to be stored as a single item in the CSV file.  Hence the commas are "escaped" by being contained by quotes in the CSV file, and the CSV interpreter returns a string.  I don't know of a way to influence the CSV interpreter in the way one can `SemanticInterpretation`, so I think some sort of post-processing is probably necessary.

Comment: You always make me feel bad coming up with these interesting and helpful answers after I voted to close (mind you, the blame is all mine!).

Answer (score 1):

Without having the .csv file to work on, as guess who it is said, this should get you where your going.

```
cord=Import["mydrive/file.csv","Data"]//ToExpression
```

Again Please give a sample of what the data is in the .csv file.